# Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.ODBCHelper?

Tags: .net, odbc, application-blocks

I've found mention of a data application block existing for ODBC, but can't seem to find it anywhere.  If i didn't have a copy of the Access DB application block I wouldn't believe it ever existed either.

Anyone know where to download either the DLL or the code-base from?

--UPDATE:  It is NOT included in either the v1, v2, or Enterprise Library versions of the Data ApplicationBlocks

Thanks,
Brian Swanson

Comment: SOS's link is correct.  I had to download it the other day.  ApplicationBlocks seems to have been left by the wayside my LINQ and ORM frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of .net are you interested in using the ODBC block on?

The Enterprise library has a Data Access component.  It is useful on SQL, Oracle, and ODBC.  Just set a different provider name in the .config file 
EX:

<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Dsn=Datasource;uid=UserID;pwd=Password"
     providerName=**"System.Data.Odbc"** />

At that point, the data access code is "standardized" and looks identical for SQL, Oracle, and ODBC

EX:

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling

    Public Class MyClass

    Private dbMyDatabase As Database

    dbMyDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyConnection")

    Public Function GetMyData(ByVal FacilityCode As String) As Data.DataSet

            Try
                Dim SQL As String
                SQL = "SELECT * from MyDataTable"
                Dim cmd As Data.Common.DbCommand = dbMyDatabase.GetSqlStringCommand(SQL)
                Return dbMyDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "All")
                Throw
            End Try
        End Function 

    End Class
```

The address for the latest Enterprise Library is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx

This is assuming you are using .net 3x.

Also note that we are using the Exception Handling block in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F63D1F0A-9877-4A7B-88EC-0426B48DF275&displaylang=en

pretty sure its in there